# Система проверки учебных заданий

Tags: java, classloader

Я хотел бы реализовать проверку учебных проектов, т.е. преподаватель пишет задание и проверку, ученик выполняет задание, ученик загружает java файл(ы) система проверяет задания.

На данный момент единственным путем решения который я вижу:
- Использования Junit для тестов
- Компиляция предоставляемых классов ученика и загрузка их через собственную реализацию classloader с правами установленными в SecurityManager

1. Как наилучшим образом реализовать это в java. Нет ли уже подобных проектов ?
2. Правильно ли я понимаю, что с помощью SecurityManager я могу полностью проконтролировать реализацию ученика(что ученик не полезет в файловую систему, сеть, запустит выполнение приложения и не полезет в реализуемый код(нужно ли мне для этого еще и отделить обычный classloader от реализуемого мной) ) ?
3. Я не знаком c docker но как я понимаю он позволяет запускать изолированные приложения не отъедая лишние ресурсы, не будет ли он лучшим решением чем SecurityManager+classloader ?

Comment: Ну что, разобрались?

Answer (score 1):

В качестве основы я бы сделал так:

1. Ученик получает файл .java с шаблоном задания
2. Для этого задания уже готов junit тест
3. Ученик загружает выполненное задания в какую либо дроп зону
4. Программа проверяющая задание, поднимает Docker контейнер с java, подключается к нему через ssl, компилирует там это задание при помощи javac, запускает JUnit тесты и пишет лог
5. Ученик получает обработанный лог

Соорудить это все можно при помощи Spring Boot.

Docker, на мой взгляд, наилучший вариант, поскольку он обладает всеми преимуществами виртуальной машины не являясь таковой. К примеру, можно использовать этот контейнер: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/java/

Если же использования докера вызывает проблемы, можно поднять виртуальную машину при помощи Vagrant, скачать образ какого-нибудь Ubuntu с OpenJDK, подключиться туда по SSL и сделать все то же самое что и с докером.

В качестве альтернативы, можно еще попробовать компилировать код прямо в рантайме: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and
Но тогда точно придется трогать SecurityManager.